# Loaded html scroll is not smooth

Tags: javascript, html, swift, scroll, wkwebview

I have my hybrid app working fully functional, but I found my app content scrolling little laggy. 
I have disabled my webview scrolled.
`webKitView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false`

But the html that is being loaded has the scrolls enabled in it. It is scrolling but user experience in that is not that satisfactory.

I had tried with this `webKitView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` too. But did not see any improvement in the behaviour. I

How can I improve the scroll lagginess?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. You want the view to scroll or not to scroll? If yes you are struggling with the scrolling being laggy?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I had to add a css in my web page